Profiling .NET Executable file
I am following the instructions at the link. As per the instruction, I set the following environment variables.
Can I set an environment variable for an application using a shortcut in Windows?
I am monitoring the .NET console application from the batch file. I set the environment variables below.
@echo off
set path=%path%
set COR_PROFILER={948834CF-5AE5-48DD-AGB7-5ES7A5BE89DD}
set COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
set COR_PROFILER_PATH_32=<actual Path>
set COR_PROFILER_PATH_64=<actual Path>
start "Title" "Path to my exe."

While starting the process, I am getting the below error message from the event viewer.
.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed during CoCreate Instance.  Profiler CLSID:'{948834CF-5AE5-48DD-AGB7-5ES7A5BE89DD}'. HRESULT: 0x8007007e. Process ID (decimal): 21880. Message ID: [0x2504].
I have confirmed that there is no 3'rd party profiler in my machine. kindly let me know the issue. What I missed.

I think you forgot to add the link to your question.

Sorry! Now I added the link.
